# Remove package path from `sys.path` installed via `pip install -e`

Tags: python, pip

I think I messed up a bit... I was trying to use pip to install a local project as a dependency of another project, and I used
`pip install -e PATH_TO_PROJECT`
and now the path to the project is in `sys.path`, (I have already changed the way I install the local project (I installed it in the client code using github)) and I deleted the `.egg-info` file from the `pip install -e` project.

How can I remove said project path from `sys.path`?

(Here is my `sys.path` output)

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.path
['',
 '/usr/lib/python37.zip',
 '/usr/lib/python3.7',
 '/usr/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload',
 '~/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages',
 '~/Projects/my_project', # <- local project path installed via `pip install -e`
 '/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages',
 '/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages']
```

**EDIT:** when I try uninstalling via `pip uninstall project_name` or `pip uninstall PATH_TO_PROJECT` I get this error

```
You must give at least one requirement to uninstall (see "pip help uninstall")
```

Comment: Start using virtualenv quick.  Crapping Python packages all over /usr, /usr/local, and ~/.local quickly becomes an unmanageable mess.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `~/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/` lookup the file `my_project.egg-link`. Remove it. From the file `easy-install.pth` in the same `site-packages/` delete the line `~/Projects/my_project`. Check with `pip list --local` and `python -c "import sys; print(sys.path)"`.

Comment: Thanks. btw, (I forgot to mention it in the question as well) I didn't see the package in `pip freeze` output...

Comment: I have installed a module by "python setup.py --user" and there is only one directory of the module in the path but easy-install.pth. I can't do any more and by removing ...egg-info, the path still remains in sys.path. What can I do more?